# Как скопировать запрос as fetch через python

Tags: python, консоль, сеть, fetch, put

[image]

При добавлении предмета в корзину появляется PUT запрос

[image]

Вот этот запрос 'loadCart?cartType=consu...

Нужно скопировать его copy as fetch и записать в отдельный файл. При попытке сделать этот через сам запрос в console выдавало ошибку 423 locked о запрете